# Angular Controller/Factory calling API in wrong order

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-controller, angular-factory

I have the following factory and controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.core')
    .factory('Auth', ['$http', function AuthFactory($http) {

        return {
            NavAuth: function (Tab) {
                return $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'Dashboard/AuthorizeNavItem', params: { Name: Tab } });
            }
        }

    }]);
})();


angular
.module('myapp')
.controller('IndexController', ['fuseTheming', 'msNavigationService', 'Auth', function (fuseTheming, msNavigationService, Auth) {
    var vm = this;

    //Define the tabs
    msNavigationService.saveItem('app', {
        title: 'QPSTool',
        group: true,
        weight: 1
    });

    msNavigationService.saveItem('app.dashboard', {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'icon-tile-four',
        state: 'app.dashboard',
        weight: 1
    });

    Auth.NavAuth('IT').success(function (result) {
        if (result == 'Authorized') {
            msNavigationService.saveItem('app.it', {
                title: 'IT',
                icon: 'icon-monitor',
                weight: 2
            });
        }
    });

    Auth.NavAuth('Users').success(function (result) {
        if (result == 'Authorized') {
            msNavigationService.saveItem('app.it.users', {
                title: 'Users',
                state: 'app.it.users',
                weight: 1
            });
        }
    });

    Auth.NavAuth('Admin').success(function (result) {
        if (result == 'Authorized') {
            msNavigationService.saveItem('app.admin', {
                title: 'Admin',
                icon: 'icon-radioactive',
                weight: 3
            });
        }
    });

    Auth.NavAuth('NavControl').success(function (result) {
        if (result == 'Authorized') {
            msNavigationService.saveItem('app.admin.navcontrol', {
                title: 'Navigation Auth',
                state: 'app.admin.navcontrol',
                weight: 1
            });
        }
    });

    // Data
    vm.themes = fuseTheming.themes;
}]);
```

What the factory method NavAuth does is it takes a navigation item name as a parameter and tells us whether a user is allowed to access this item.

The issue I am having is that in the controller when I use `msNavigationService.saveItem` data is being returned in a random order. So It will return the authorized for `NavControl` before `IT`.

This causes the side navigation to not render correctly.

How do I make it so that things will run in the order that I have specified in the controller (i.e. how do i make it wait until one is done to do the other)?

Comment: since these are all promises, their order is never guaranteed.  Your best bet would be to rewrite the logic to save the results into an array, do something like `$q.all` to process all the promises, and then iterate through the array to do the rendering in the order you want.

Comment: $q.all() will combine all the  promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the individual promises are resolved.

Comment: as a side note, `.success()` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15157) for quite a while and have been [removed completely in angular 1.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b54a39e2029005e0572fbd2ac0e8f6a4e5d69014).  you should be using `.then()`, but in this case I wouldn't recommend using `call.then(makeAnother().then(makeAnother().then(makeAnother())))` since that could get quite messy.

Comment: @Claies, I didn't know that. I'll be using `.then()` from now on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue would not be resolved by `$q.all` but by putting the `then` part of the promise, so you would do something like

```
NavAuth('IT').then(function (res) {
  // doWhatever IT function does;
  ...
  NavAuth('NavControl').then(function (res) {
    // doWhatever NavControl function does;
    ...
  })
})
```

With the `then` of the promises you enforce the code to be executed in an order, with `$q.all()` you won't execute everything untill all the promises you pass to the `$q.all()` have finished, and that is not what you want

Comment: This worked very well for my purposes. I tried it before, but my implementation was way off.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the promises in a specific order, trigger them using .then(). If you would rather do them all at once and then order appropriately, use .all() to resolve the promises, then order your data.

Comment: That is also true, if you can pass all the data of the resolved promises at once, you can always trigger them all at the same time and this will be faster than making them consecutive by using `then`